# Order the nvarchar values in SQL

Tags: sql

When trying to order with the query

```
SELECT ACTT 
FROM AIKUcusSaatleri
ORDER BY ACTT
```

this function not working properly. The result is shown below;

```
ACTT
0
1040
1042,6
873,8
996,6
996,6
997,6
```

What is the reason of this problem?

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Comment: It perfectly makes sense. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Use a numeric sensitive collation.

Answer (score 5):

But these are ordered correctly . . . If you realize that they are strings.

Store numbers as numbers.  If you want to sort strings as numbers, you need to convert them.  You can try:

```
order by cast(actt as numeric(20, 2))
```

That may or may not work with the comma, depending on your database and internationalization settings.  It should work if you replace the comma with a decimal point:

```
order by cast(replace(actt, ',', '.') as numeric(20, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function available with your code, `order by` is a clause & perhaps you need :

Assuming the `SQL Server` DBMS if so, then you can do :

```
SELECT ACTT 
FROM AIKUcusSaatleri 
ORDER BY LEFT(ACCT, CHARINDEX(',', ACTT)-1);
```

if `,` treat as decimal `.`, then you need to do conversations :

```
SELECT ACTT 
FROM AIKUcusSaatleri 
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(ACTT, ',', '.') AS NUMERIC(20, 2));
```

Comment: Apparently OP is using commas as decimal separator.